# Notfication if bounty expires on another site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, notifications

Recently I set a bounty on a superuser question. Unfortunately I was very very busy for the next week and only logged in once or twice on SO. Now the problem is, the bounty on superuser expired unnoticed. Wouldn't it be a good idea if a user is notified if a bounty expires even if he is visiting another SE site?

Comment: Didn't you get an email notification?

Comment: That's not the problem. But to answer your question: no i didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your email must be invalid or misconfigured; there are always email notifications of expiring bounties before they happen.

I just checked your account here and on SU... and sure enough, no email.

So the "fix" for this "bug" is to provide a valid email address in your account. Then use the "copy profile to all sites" button to make sure it propagates everywhere in the network.

Comment: But on the dropdown list with all the notifications, I can add an email address in the email settings. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Roflcoptr we did find a bug in the bounty email logic which will be fixed on the next deploy.  It will use the verified email from your account if you do not have email set on your profile.

Comment: Thanks, now I received an email for this bounty. It seems to work!